# Knockoutjs computed passing parameters

Tags: javascript, binding, knockout.js, observable

I am wondering if it is possible with knockoutjs to pass arguments when binding.

I am binding a list of checkboxes and would like to bind to a single computed observable in my viewmodel. In my viewmodel (based on parameter passed to the read function) I want to return true/false based on certain conditions.

```
var myViewModel=function(){
    this.myprop=ko.computed({read: function(){
    //would like to receive an argument here to do my logic and return based on argument.
}
});
};

<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myprop(someval1)" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myprop(someval2)" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myprop(someval3)" />
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Create a function whose sole purpose is to return a computed observable.  It may take in parameters as you wanted.  It will have to be a separate computed observable if you want it to be a two-way binding.

Then in your binding, call that function with the appropriate arguments.  The computed observable it returns will be bound to in your view and will update as usual.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/WGKBA/) where I used this technique for creating event handlers.  You can do something similar here.

You can keep it clean by making the function a method on the observable.  Either by adding to the `ko.observable.fn` prototype or adding it directly to the observable instance.

```
ko.observable.fn.bit = function (bit) {
    return ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return !!(this() & bit);
        },
        write: function (checked) {
            if (checked)
                this(this() | bit);
            else
                this(this() & ~bit);
        }
    }, this);
};
// or
function ViewModel() {
    this.flags = ko.observable(0);

    this.flags.bit = function (bit) {
        return ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return !!(this() & bit);
            },
            write: function (checked) {
                if (checked)
                    this(this() | bit);
                else
                    this(this() & ~bit);
            }
        }, this);
    }.bind(this.flags);
}
```

Then apply to your view

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: flags.bit(0x1)"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: flags.bit(0x2)"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: flags.bit(0x4)"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: flags.bit(0x8)"/>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/M4sKG/29/)

---

However if you are just trying to bind all those checkboxes to a single value in your view model, you don't need to do that.  Use the `checked` binding on an array in your view model and give your checkboxes a value.  Every checked value will be added to the array.  And it will be a two way binding.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedValues, value: 1"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedValues, value: 2"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedValues, value: 3"/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedValues, value: 4"/>
```

```
var viewModel = {
    checkedValues: ko.observableArray([])
};
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jeff1203/M4sKG/)

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is decent, but if you have a function that generates a ko.computed for each checkbox, you are adding unnecessary overhead with multiple anonymous computed observables, which adds up quickly when your checkbox lists exceed 4-5 options.

This is a simpler implementation of a bitwise scenario, but the computed function can be whatever need be.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedList, value: 1" />
<label>Value 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedList, value: 2" />
<label>Value 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedList, value: 4" />
<label>Value 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedList, value: 8" />
<label>Value 8</label>
```

Script:

```
var vm = function() {
    var vm = this;

    this.checkedList = ko.observableArray();
    this.bitwiseValue = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return vm.checkedList().reduce(function (prev, curr) {
                return prev | curr;
            }, 0);
        },
        write: function (myVal) {
            vm.checkedList.removeAll();
            var placeValue = 1;

            while(myVal > 0) {
                if((myVal % 2) == 1) {
                    alert(placeValue);
                    vm.checkedList.push(placeValue.toString());
                }

                myVal = myVal >>> 1;                    
                placeValue = placeValue * 2;
            }
        }
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/i_vargas3/RYQgg/

Comment: this works great, thank you.  However, if I assign a value to bitwiseValue it does not check the boxes where it should.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In the example fiddle you had to hit Return in order for the change to occur. I modified the binding to include a 'valueUpdate' entry on input

Comment: That is Awesome thanks!  Here is one last question, seems like adding vm.bitwiseValue(6); before the applyBindings will not check any of the boxes off the bat.  Is there a way to set it as if you got the value from a database?

Comment: Sorry, I was not instancing the vm, so KO was bound to the function instead of a new'd up instance. I have modified it slightly to work to your desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason to use a `computed` value.  Simply define a function in your View Model and bind the `checked` to it.

Below is a very simplistic example.

--

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEven(1)" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEven(2)" />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isEven(3)" />​
```

JS

```
var MyViewModel=function(){
    this.isEven = function(num) {
        return (num % 2) == 0;
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

​--

That being said it is a good idea to try and push as much of the logic into your View Model as is possible.  It would be advisable to create a View Model that models your checkbox as an object, and then the logic as to if the checkbox should be checked could be encapsulated inside.

--

EDIT: Based on the requirement to do two-way binding I have written an extender to manage an observable.

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/j6zLW/5/

```
ko.extenders.bitwise = function(target, bitCount) { 
    target.bits = [];    
    target.checked = ko.observableArray();

    // Create bit array based on requested number of bits
    for (i=bitCount-1; i>=0; i--) {
        target.bits.push(''+Math.pow(2, i));
    }        

    // Define a function to create bits
    function makeBits(newValue) {
       var num = !isNaN(newValue) ? parseInt(newValue) : 0;
       var arr = [];
       for (i=0; i<target.bits.length; i++) {
          var bitValue = parseInt(target.bits[i]);
          if ((num & bitValue) == bitValue) arr.push(target.bits[i]);
       }
       target.checked(arr);
    }

    // Define a function to combine bits
    function makeBitwise(newBits) {
       var num = 0;
       for (i=0; i<target.bits.length; i++) {
         if (newBits.indexOf(target.bits[i]) > -1) num += parseInt(target.bits[i]);
       }
       target(num);
    }

    // Create initial bits
    makeBits(target());

    // Make bits whenever the value changes
    target.subscribe(makeBits);

    // Make number whenever the bits change
    target.checked.subscribe(makeBitwise);

    // Return the original observable
    return target;
};

var MyViewModel=function(){
    var self = this;
    this.number = ko.observable(2).extend({ bitwise: 8});

};
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());​
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that works like a onetime binding, isn't it? How can I push the change back to checkbox from viewModel if the value is changed? Also when the checkbox's checked state change how can I update my viewmodel?

Comment: It depends what you need to do.  Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/j6zLW/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle! That is pretty close to what I need. Any idea why is function isSet not called when you check/uncheck the checkboxes in UI?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extender that manages a numeric observable as a sequence of bits.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/j6zLW/5/

Comment: Thanks for your updated sample, looks like I'll have to learn a bit more about knockoutjs, didn't knew about extenders. However Jeff's answer is a much simpler solution so am sorry I'll have to accept his answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics, it seems like what you should be doing is defining a ko.observableArray or computed array value

HTML:

```
myprop: <input data-bind="value: myprop">
<div data-bind="foreach: selections">
  <label>
    <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected"/>
  </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $(function() {
    function Model() {
        this.self = this
        self.myprop = ko.observable(14)
        self.bits = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128]
        self.selections = ko.computed(function() {
            return self.bits.map(function(bit) {
                console.log(myprop() & bit)
                return {
                    value: bit,
                    selected: (myprop() & bit) == bit
                }
            })
        })
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new Model())
})
```

and not passing values from the markup to define the model state

Comment: Nice suggestion, not sure if it going to work for my situation. My property is a bitwise flag and based on any checkbox being checked it need will affect other checkboxes in the list. Not sure if I am managing to explain my situation properly :(

Comment: Let me try to explain a bit further. Say myprop=14 and I got three checkboxes whom bit values are 2,4,8. In this case all three checkboes needs to be checked. If I change myprop=2, in this case only the first checkbox needs to be checked and rest of the two needs to unchecked. Am thinking about custom binding handler but not sure how to do it. I hope this helps in explaining the task in hand.

Comment: Please see the edited example above.  John's approach works too, but prefer the logic and data being in the model, not parameters from markup.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But like John's solution, this doesn't update the value when the checkboxes are checked/unchecked from UI.

Comment: If you need update based on checks, then it sounds like you may thinking of this binding backwards.  I'll try and update example later.